# Bind domain name to a port no having IIS & APACHE

Tags: apache, iis

I have IIs and Apache installed on my server. IIs on port no 80 and Apache on 81 .
I have websites on both services. For example domain name for a website is "www.wx.com" when this domain is accessed on internet it by default goes to IIs service i.e port no 80 on my server. what should be done so that domain name will be directed to apache service i.e port no 81 ?

Comment: Any reason why you've unaccepted my answer after almost two years?

Comment: I am sorry, I did it by mistake..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "bind" domain names to ports. You have one of a few options:

1. In your browser (if this is just for development) browse to `http://www.wx.com:81`. Not ideal for public facing sites.
2. Set up a site on IIS to redirect or reverse proxy your apache site using something like ARR:

   > http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing
3. Prevent IIS from binding to port 80 on all IP addresses (or just the IP address you want to allocate to apache) and configure your apache instance to listen on a specific IP address not used by IIS